# Duplicate Lines (Data) checking in Multiple Files

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

I have Created multiple files with Duplicate Serial Numbers from JMeter Response Data.

```
Duplicate.txt    Duplicate1.txt      Duplicate2.txt Etc.....

C5FV55WGJ1       C5FV55WGJ1
C5FX1N2572       C5FX1N2578
C5G0F54VP3       C5G0F54VP9
C5G77R09C4       C5G77R0910
C5G7L33Y25       C5G7L33Y11
C5G7X7NWY6       C5G7X7NW12
C5FX1N2577       C5FX1N2513
```

Like above txt data files I have multiple fils in one directory. Now I want to compare all the .txt file with each one .txt file.

If duplicate found any Serial Number .txt file, want to create one *Double Duplicate.txt* file with Serial Numbers and .txt File in JMeter Groovy JMeter PostProcessor.

Exp;

```
Double Duplicate.txt

C5FV55WGJ1 (Duplicate.txt & Duplicate1.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet:

```
new File('/path/to/folder/with/your/duplicate/files').listFiles().each { file ->
    List<String> lines = file.readLines()
    new File('/path/to/folder/with/your/duplicate/files').listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return !file.getName().equals(name)
        }
    }).each { otherfile ->
        List<String> otherLines = otherfile.readLines()
        lines.each { line ->
            if (otherLines.contains(line)) {
                new File('Double Duplicate.txt') << line << ' ('<< file.getName() << ' & ' << otherfile.getName() << ')' << System.getProperty('line.separator')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)